# Why do some of my devices turn off and then back on when I turn off my space heater?

Tags: power

I have a small portable heater which is connected to the second outlet at the wall where the power strip for my computer is also connected.

Here is a link to the heater I use:
http://www.viewpoints.com/Sunbeam-Portable-Compact-Ceramic-Heater--446866-reviews

Whenever I turn OFF the heater, one of my monitors (I have three on the same strip) turns off and then back on and the USB web cam which is connected to my computer disconnects and reconnects (there is a blip-bloop sound from my computer).

Why is this?

Comment: Might be inductive kick from the fan turning off.

Comment: Seems like your outlet my have trouble supporting the load of the heater, this a big jump in line voltage when it is turned off. Also inductive kickback is possible. Maybe try extension cord with built-in surge/noise suppressor, but they can be expensive.

Comment: Everything computer-related on the second outlet is on a surge protector. I just find it very strange that it affects my USB webcam which is plugged into the computer.

Comment: hm, can you measure the AC voltage at these outlets? if not: do you observe a difference in brightness when using incandescent lamps with the heater on and off? It'd also be relevant to know the age of your house's cabling and the country that house stands in.